# Xamarin form: How display activityindicator instantly while in async task?

Tags: user-interface, xamarin, task, indicator

```
    public async Task ShowIndicator(Func<Task> action)
    {
        actionEnabled = false;
        IndicatorVisibility = true;
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        await action.Invoke();
        IndicatorVisibility = false;
        actionEnabled = true;
    }
```

I am using the above code to run some Task while showing the indicator by setting the viewmodel properties of the IndicatorVisibility. If I placed the Task.Delay, it will ok but will slow down the code. If I am not placed it, the indicator won't show straightaway coz it will set to second to last indicator visibility to false.

Is it possible to wait the indicator displayed itself before execute the action from the above code?

Comment: `IndicatorVisibility = false;` will execute after `action`. If `action` just needs little time to run? It will cause the flash of activityIndicator(show and dismiss 
almost at the same time). You can try to post some code about `action`.

Comment: Yes that is what was happening.

Comment: If the action method doesn't need too much time, this will be. Then you call the `Task.Delay(5000);` to let the activityIndicator show 5 seconds. You have done the right thing and what's your problem?

Comment: Is ok if that is the proper way of doing it. cheers

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. This has the exact problem, the activity indicator never appers or appears too late:

```
async void GoDetail(object obj)
{
    Busy = true;

    DetailsViewModel.Initialize(_items, this.SelectedItem);

    await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new xxxPage());

    Busy = false;

}
```

This fixes it, activity indicator appears instantly...:

```
async void GoDetail(object obj)
{
    Busy = true;
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        DetailsViewModel.Initialize(_items, this.SelectedItem);

        await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new xxxPage());

        Busy = false;
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much   ♥

Comment: I can't, because I am not the topic owner

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 public Task ShowIndicator(Func<Task> action)
    {
        actionEnabled = false;
        IndicatorVisibility = true;

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            await action.Invoke();
            IndicatorVisibility = false;
            actionEnabled = true;
        });
    }
```